# Alternative for proxy.conf.json in vue without vue-cli?

Tags: vue.js

I want to make requests to api on another website.

I know that in Angular you can have a file proxy.conf.json with something like this

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "website.com",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this in vue if I don't use vue-cli?

Comment: What tool are you using if not `vue-cli`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using express server with webpack dev middleware and `express-http-proxy`